# gnome 14.04 battery guage doesn't work

Tags: battery

The icon is there, and it works sometimes, but other times it will not change at all. It will read full, or some state of charge and not move until my computer dies. I sometimes forget that I am unplugged and don't get any kind of warning and then poof.

Is there a battery service I can restart or something?